# Nothing handles action on immediate event - Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Alright so I am running into this issue, check it out

http://jsbin.com/rarubesuxutu/1/edit?html,css,js

I am trying to send an event right after init but the event does not get handled. Instead the action just errors out. Why does Ember handle it like this? When is it ok to send an event? Is there some callback so I can set my observers?

Thanks!

Comment: Ember is not defined in your example.

Comment: Weird..it is loaded up fine in mine. I just get an error. I started with the typical ember boilerplate for issues on github. Try commenting out `this.send("test");` That's where the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. I had a misunderstanding of the order of the callbacks.

[Here is my updated version](http://jsbin.com/rarubesuxutu/54/edit?html,js,console). While it's not fixed it helps understand the order of the route and controller initializations. The `IndexController` init is called before the routes `setupController`. This triggers the event before the route was set.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm not sure why you want to send an action right after init, as you should be able to define all of your variables in the setupController or in the controllers init phase, so I'll show you how I would go about it. [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/rarubesuxutu/50/edit?html,js,console,output)

Effectively what you can do is on init for the controller, you can do this:

```
theTruth: false,
setTheTruth: function(){
      this.set('theTruth', true);
}.on('init'),
```

Then you can have an observer that watches for changes on this variable like so:

```
truthChanged:function(){
    console.log("TRUTH HAS CHANGED");
}.observes('this.theTruth'),
```

Ideally though, you can forgo all of this by taking advantage of the routes setupController function like so[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/rarubesuxutu/53/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    controller.set('theTruth', true);
},
```

This way you don't even deal with handling anything in the init event. However, say you have a requirement that makes you have to do anything with the init event, you should separate your observer from the .on('init') event, and let them coexist separately. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @abuani for your answer. I think I figured it out. Unfortunately I need the route to handle the action because it is in charge of fetching the data I need. But your answer is a good solution to my problem if I wasn't dependent on the routes for data.

Comment: The way I showed has the route handling the action, the only difference is the initial setup of "theTruth" happens in the router instead of having the controller send an action. You shouldn't have a need to bubble an action from teh controller to the route on the 'init' sequence of the controller, since the route can make any calls it needs before setting up the controller.